# opening a mp3 song opens in video instead of rythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, mp3

Any time that I try to pen a mp3 music file, it opens in video instead of rhythmbox.  is there someone that knows how to do that the music player is the program to be used?
using the latest version of Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-open.html.en

```
Select a file of the type whose default application you want to change. For example, to change which application is used to open MP3 files, select a . ...
Right-click the file and select Properties.
Select the Open With tab.
Select the application you want and click Set as default.
```